# Regex to match at least two words in a given place/paragraph

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I have a search bar which would search for places, I only want to return results if the value of the input matches at least two words regardless of their positioning. I've tried using [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) but this would only match those starting with.

If I want to search for Central Park, I could either type in the search bar "New york central park" or "Central Park New York" or simply "Central Park" and it will return the result but if I only type in "Park" or "Central", Central Park should not be returned yet

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match is a better match for your needs, and don't forget to include an space in your regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Regex isn’t going to take care of the word-comparison part, but it can help you extract words. Try solving that problem first – writing a function that can take a string as input and return an array of words – and seeing if you can use the result to make it the rest of the way.

Comment: @Ry- thanks for the suggestion, I don't know if what I am doing is correct but I split the "Central Park" string to get an array of words then loop that array and try to use regex and match the words as suggested above

Comment: The first part of that sounds correct! Can you show the code you have?

Comment: Hello @Ry sorry for the late response, please see the answer I posted, suggestions are very much welcome thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this based on the suggestions given but the code still feels like it can be still improved.

```
const places =['Central Park', 'Arches National Park', 'Bryce Canyon National Park']
const searchTerm = "Central Park"

checkIfSearchTermMatches(places, searchTerm)

function checkIfSearchTermMatches(places, searchTerm) {
  let matchedPlace = null;
  for (place of places) {
    let splitPlace = place.split(" ");
    let matchCount = 0;
    for (name of splitPlace) {
      var matchWordRegex = new RegExp(name, "i");
      const nameMatches = searchTerm.match(matchWordRegex);
      if (nameMatches && nameMatches !== null) {
        matchCount++;
      }
    }
    if (matchCount >= 2) {
      matchedPlace = place;
    }
  }
}
```